# Pack and Unpack String with Regex Mask

Tags: c#, .net, regex, masking

I am looking for a simple & fast way to pack and unpack an integer with a Regex string (without using back references).  I would think this would be an extremely obvious function of the .Net Regex library but am not finding anything.  Am I missing something?

Comment: When you refer to packing and unpacking, are you talking about a sort of compression algorithm or something else?  Sorry, the terminology you're using is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: cant understand ur question...`Examples` would help

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  I was able to find the solution (see below)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using the MaskedTextProvider.  I need be able to store a mask in my database (for example: "(000) 000-000") and apply an integer value to it.  The goal is to have a number of masks that can be dynamically bound to the integer value.